# How to properly create Android/iOS Expansion Files

Tags: haxe, openfl

Is there a proper way to create expansions files for iOS and Android apps using the command line tool (haxe or lime) or is it always just by manually making a .zip file and renaming it to match the correct pattern?

Comment: Do you really mean expansion, or do you man extension, like a C++ native extension?

Comment: I wrote correctly Expansion files, for android they are typically .OBB files. I might answer the question myself as I'm getting more info on the subject.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I have an application ready for the play store but it is larger than the 50M limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing. I also made an extension with a tool for this that simplifies the command. In addition to zipping and pushing the obb file to your device for testing, it also has the suggested google libraries to handle downloading the OBB in the case that the APK is downloaded and not the obb. https://github.com/thomasuster/android-expansion